# How many different strings can be made from letters in CHICAGOLAND, subject to constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

How many different strings can be made from the letters in CHICAGOLAND, using all letters, and such that no two vowels are adjacent to each other?

Comment: 'different strings' - of which length?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Maths SE! This is a good question, however it is generally appreciated when you include some work you have already done on the problem.

Comment: A start: There are $7$ consonants. Put down $7$ boxes to hold them, with a little gap between boxes. That gives $8$ places to insert a vowel, of which we must choose $4$.

Comment: @Alex, have you read the phrase *using all letters*?

Comment: Yes I have. String CHICAGOLANDCHICAGOLAND also uses all letters.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, write all the consonants of *CHICAGOLAND*, in the following way.
$$-C-H-C-G-L-N-D-.$$

This can be done in $ 7!/2!=2520$ ways. Now place the vowels in the gaps, can be done in $\binom{8}{4}\times 4!/2!=\binom{8}{4}\times 12$ ways, Since $a$ comes twice.

So, the total number of ways in which we can make a $11$ letter string, is $$\bbox[border:2px solid blue]{\binom{8}{4}\times 12\times 2520}$$

Comment: assuming the OP meant 'no two or more'

Comment: Please consider not giving such a complete answer to a question phrased in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create spaces the consonants leaving 1 space can be arranged in $7!/2!$ ways and these $7$ create 8 spaces ends inclu also so these $8$ can be filled by $4$ of them in ${8\choose 4}.\frac{4!}{2!}.2520 $ ways