# How many arrangements are there of the word POISONS so that no two vowels are together?

Tags: combinatorics

I actually have 3 questions to ask. You just have to say if my solution is right or not.

First question:

How many arrangements are there of the word POISONS so that no two vowels are together?

I tried:

$\frac {5!}{2!} * C(6, 3) * \frac {3!}{2!}$

Second question:

How many ways are there to place 65 different fish into 5 bowls so that each bowl has exactly 13 fish?

I tried:

P(65, 13) * P(52, 13) * P(39, 13) * P(26, 13) * P(13, 13)

Third question:

How many ways are there to distribute 13 identical blue balls and 2 identical red balls into 5 boxes with no box containing more than 1 red ball?

I tried:

C(5, 2) * C(17, 4)

Comment: Doing the first I think your way I get $(4!/2!)\binom{5}{3}(3!/2!)$.  The other two look right, assuming that the bowls are distinguishable, they are the soup bowls in front of $5$ different people. Same with boxes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Now I realize that I miscounted the consonants in the first question. So for the second question, what if they bowls are not distinguishable? Thanks!

Comment: I misread your number 2 solution, it should be binomial coefficients, or a multinomial coefficient. If indistinguishable, divide by $5!$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Is my solution to the third question wrong? you please judge this. [Mark Fischler is accusing this wrong](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632360/how-many-arrangements-are-there-of-the-word-poisons-so-that-no-two-vowels-are-to/1632392#comment3328321_1632392).

Comment: With distinguishable boxes, it is right. You counted the number of ways to place the blues, and for the reds used the standard "Stars and Bars" formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *first question:*

First place the consonants in the following way $$-P-S-N-S-,$$ so, this can be done in  $$4!/2!=12$$ ways. Now place the vowels in the gaps, so this can be done in $$\frac{\binom 53 \times 3!}2=30$$ ways. So, the total number of way is $$\bbox[border:2px solid red]
{12\times 30=360}$$ ways.

*Note: [here is similar answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629310/how-many-different-strings-can-be-made-from-letters-in-chicagoland-subject-to-c/1629321#1629321)*.

For the *second one:*

The order of the fishes is irrelevant, so, answer is $$\bbox[border:2px solid red]
{\binom {65}{13}\times\binom {52}{13}\times\binom {39}{13}\times\binom {23}{13}\times\binom {13}{13}\\=\frac{65!}{(13!)^5}}$$

For the *third one:*

Here I *assume that the boxes are distinct.* So, you have only to count the number of blue balls in one box.

Let, $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5$ be the three box, and define $x_i$ as the number of balls in the $i^{th}$ box. So, you have to count the number of solutions to the equation $$\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i=13,$$ which is $$\binom{17}{4}.$$ And now choose any $2$ box out of $5$ to keep the $2$ red balls, in $\binom 52$ ways, so, number of ways is $$\bbox[border:2px solid red]
{\binom{17}{4}\times \binom 52}$$

Comment: You blew it on the third answer, because the two red balls can be in the same box.  So in is $\binom{6}{2}$.  But I like your solution to the first problem better than mine, so I am not downvoting the answer.

Comment: @MarkFischler, read my comment to your post.

Comment: @helpme, I did so, Pick up any $2$ box out of $5$ to keep the $2$ red balls. simply *choose two out of five*.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey. Oops, I meant to reply to Mark Fischler/

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, what you missed is that one would not care about the *order* of the fish in a specific bowl (they will after all swim around and mix that order up anyway).  So instead of permutations you should be using combinations, and the answer is 
$$\binom{65}{13} \binom{52}{13} \binom{39}{13} \binom{26}{13} \binom{13}{13}$$

For your third question, assuming the boxes are distinguishable, you have one part of the problem right:  You have $\binom{13+4}{4}=\binom{17}{4}$ ways to distribute the 13 blue balls among the boxes.  You then have to independently distribute the 2 red balls, which you can do in $\binom{2+4}{4}=\binom{6}{2}$ ways.  So the answer is 
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{17}{4}$$
and your answer is correct in the limit as $5\to 6$. (LOL)

Your first question is actually a lot harder.  First you have to answer the "hard part" question "In how many ways can I arrange three arbitrary vowels and four arbitrary consonants such that no two vowels are consecutive."  IN the end you will multiply that answer by $12$ ways to permute the 4 consonants with two of them identical, times $3$ ways to permute the 3 vowels with two of them identical.

To do the hard part , break the problem up into four cases: Either (a) the first and last letters are vowels, or (b) the first and last letters are  consonants, or (c) the first is a vowel and the last is a consonant, or (d) the first is a consonant and the last is a vowel.

In case (a), each vowel other than the first must be preceded by a consonant, so we have to place a consonant in position 6, and we can "glue" a consonant in front of the first vowel.  We then have to place two consonants and one c-v pair into three possible slots; there are 3 ways to do this.

In case (b), there is only one valid arrangement, with the consonants and vowels alternating. In case (c) each of the remaining 2 vowels must be preceded by a consonant, so we have to arrange 2 c-v pairs and one loos consonant into 3 positions, which is done in 3 ways.  And case (d) has, by symmetry, the same answer as case (c).  The total is 10, so the answer to the first question is $$12 \cdot 3 \cdot 10 = 360$$.

Comment: Solution to the third question is wrong, since OP says *no box containing more than 1 red ball*, so, $\binom 62$ will sometime contain two red balls in one bowl, and other boxes remain empty, that's not allowed. See my answer.